# VBA Dynamic Table (ListObject)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, object

So, after some research I miss something somewhere... First, I linked my SQL recordset to my spreadsheet so I managed to fetch 9999 rows and 16 columns starting by Cell "B21". Onto this, I created a table named "MyScreener" with this piece of code:

```vb
Sub Create_Table()

    Dim Rn As Range
    Set Rn = shtEquity.Range("B21").CurrentRegion
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = shtEquity.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Rn, xlYes)
    With tbl
        .Name = "MyScreener"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium18"
    End With

End Sub
```

Cool so now I have a new column to add to my table, I tried some pieces of code like this one for example:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim lcol As Integer

Set tbl = shtEquity.ListObjects("MyScreener")

lrow = tbl.Range.Rows.count
lcol = tbl.Range.Columns.count

tbl.Resize tbl.Range.Resize(lrow, lcol)
```

This one compile but does nothing, giving lrow = 9980 and lcol = 16 which is obviously does not taking into account my last (an seventeenth) column.

Is there anyone that can just give a tip to create a table that dynamically updates itself when I fetch a new request ? Like each request, SQL send new amount of rows and as it's linked with my sspreadsheet already it would be nice that the table within the spreadhseet updates too.

Hope my explanation will be clear enough.

Thanks in advance for looking at !

Comment: You don't need vba to get dynamic ranges. Just a named range with this formula: `=OFFSET(STARTINGCELL,0,0,COUNTA(STARTINGCOLUMNG),COUNTA(STARTINGROW))` this way your range will grow with your data. This works unless you delete your cells on the SQL sheet*

Comment: If you've already added a column, why do you need to resize `tbl`? It should resize when you add the column.

Comment: Thank you so much guy's, I'll try to use that actually, so if I undesrtand well this excel formula readjust each time the table's size change ? It can be larger or smaller from what I understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused.
Ordinarily, if you've already added a column to the table, it will resize.

If this code is to enlarge the table to create an extra column first, then you have to add one (1) to the current column count.

So:

```
   tbl.Resize tbl.Range.Resize(lRow, lCol + 1)
```

By the way, you should declare lrow and lcol as Long and not Integer.

Integer will limit your rows to 32767, and, internally, integers get converted to Longs anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld, sorry if it was unclear, basically, I need to find a way to resize my named range (which is my table) each time I run my code. For example it can be 1450 rows and then 10 rows and after 1450 back